# jQuery repeating animation and breaking functionality of forms

Tags: jquery

I've got the following code which works well for a couple of clicks on the forgot pass link, then when it goes through an entire click cycle it just breaks loading all the animations again and not stopping. I've pasted relevent codes below and a fiddle link.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.forgot').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#login-form').fadeOut(400);
        $('#forgot-pass-form').delay(200).fadeIn(400);
        $(this).text('Suddenly remembered your details? Click here');
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            $('#forgot-pass-form').fadeOut(400);
            $('#login-form').delay(200).fadeIn(400);
            $(this).text('Forgotten your login details?');
        });
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DR7PP/1/)

Comment: Correction, you 'have not' OR 'will' post a fiddle link.

Comment: lol i forgot, its on there now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are attaching another click handler to the clicked element every time it is clicked, so when the element is clicked it's several click handlers are executed at once. One option is using `fadeToggle` method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.forgot').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#login-form').fadeToggle(400);
        $('#forgot-pass-form').fadeToggle(400);
        $(this).text(function(_, textContent) {
            return textContent === 'Forgotten your login details?' 
                   ? 'Suddenly remembered your details? Click here' 
                   : 'Forgotten your login details?'
        });
    });
});
```

Improved fade effect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.forgot').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('form:visible').fadeOut(400, function(){
           $(this).siblings('form').fadeIn();
        });
        $(this).text(function (_, textContent) {
            return textContent === 'Forgotten your login details?' ? 'Suddenly remembered your details? Click here' : 'Forgotten your login details?'
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WTtNS/

Comment: My friend that works absolutely perfectly and +1 for teaching me new techniques, thanks very much!